# Не могу передать аргументы-пути в кавычках с backslash в консольную программу на C#

Tags: c#

Два аргумента консольной программы представляют из себя пути, оканчивающиеся на backslash и заключенные в кавычки.

```
program.exe "path1\" "path2\"
```

В программе эти аргументы из-за оконечных backslash сливаются в один `args[0]` = `C:\path1" C:\path2"`.

Вид аргументов задается не мной и я не могу изменить их стиль. Как принять пути правильно?

Comment: Попробуйте заэскейпить backslash, то есть \ => \\

Comment: Если совсем все плохо, то вот [набор костылей](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6040946/12888024).

Comment: Что-то на `"path1\\" "path2\\"` у меня не воспроизводится. Ошибка возникнает именно на этих значениях? Если нет, то укажите полный текст команды, возможно проблема в чем-то другом.

Comment: @defaultlocale была моя ошибка при редактировании вопроса, я исправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот есть такой код

```cs
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetCommandLine();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---Environment.CommandLine---");
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.CommandLine);

        Console.WriteLine("---args[0]---");
        Console.WriteLine(args[0]);

        Console.WriteLine("---kernel32.dll / GetCommandLine()---");
        IntPtr ptr = GetCommandLine();
        string commandLine = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr);
        Console.WriteLine(commandLine);

        Console.WriteLine("---Parse previous output---");
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(commandLine, @"\""(.+?)\""");
        string[] arguments = matches.Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).Skip(1).ToArray();
        foreach (string s in arguments)
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Если запустить с таким образом

```
ConsoleApp1.exe "path1\" "path2\"
```

То получится вот такой вывод

```
---Environment.CommandLine---
C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ConsoleApp1.dll "path1\" path2\""
---args[0]---
path1" path2"
---kernel32.dll / GetCommandLine()---
"C:\Source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ConsoleApp1.exe" "path1\" "path2\"
---Parse previous output---
path1\
path2\
```

Возможно вам нужен как раз третий способ, как источник данных для того, чтобы распарсить командную строку.